# как вытащить текст из блюра

Tags: javascript, html, css

ребят, помогите решить проблему, гоняю уже несколько дней.

### нужно вытащить текст из блюра

вопрос решён, убрал с родительского стиля текст и настроил, как нужно было для меня.

Comment: проблему решил, оказалось всё куда проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, а как вы эту проблему гоняете и в чем?
Решается за минуту - лезете в веб-инспектор, тыкаете в нужный элемент и копируете текст (если он не часть графики). Если не успеваете, или текст размыт постоянно - нужно убрать блюр (проще всего сразу везде):

```
* {
filter: unset!important;
-webkit-filter: unset!important;
-webkit-animation: unset!important;
}
```

Comment: мне только текст нужно вытащить, но вот что-то и щас не понял ничего(

Comment: В браузере правой кнопкой в нужное место тычете и выбираете "просмотреть код" (если хром) или "исследовать элемент" (если ФФ). Попадаете в участок кода страницы, в котором находится искомый элемент. Копируете оттуда содержимое. Предложенный мной стиль можно там же, в правой части, добавить к стилям страницы, он применится и размытие спадет - тогда можно будет копировать текст прямо со страницы, выделив его мышкой.

Comment: эта же не работает : https://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/v6xqv5y3/2/

Comment: Максим, работало бы, если б было задано как положено. А у вас фильтр переопределен для `<p>`, но его родительский `<div>` остался размытым. надо применять ко всем элементам: https://jsfiddle.net/v6xqv5y3/3/